# Progress bar appears with loading string before fragment gets loaded in HoneyComb 3.0

Tags: android

I am writing an Android 3.0 application in which I displays a List. Clicking on any item on list will display another list which is a Fragment. Say this Fragment as Fragment1. I will display this fragment every time I click 1,2,4 listitems.

But when I click ListItem3 I will display another Fragment say Fragment2 besides Fragment1. My question is before clicking the ListItem3, a ProgressBar with "Loading" text is displayed at a place where Fragment2 is supposed to be displayed when I click ListItem3. The ProgressBar is there even after the Fragment2 is displayed. What is the reason why this ProgressBar is displayed?

Comment: Could you post some code please? It's difficult to figure out what you're talking about without code. The layouts would also be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

I too was stuck with the similar problem and the answer of @JasonKnight in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318175/fragment-loading-spinner-dialog-in-honeycomb) question solved my trouble. I did:

```
public class PoursFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedState);
    this.setListShown(true);
    ...
```